# Deduce the finite Ramsey theorem from the infinite case.

Tags: solution-verification, coloring, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I'd like to ask for some checking of my proof for the statement below.

> Using the fact that every $\textbf{red/blue}$ colouring of $\mathbb{N} \choose 2$ contains an infinite monochromatic clique, show that for every positive integer $t \geq 2$, there exists a finite $n$ such that every $\textbf{red/blue}$ colouring of $E(K_n)$ contains a monochromatic $K_t$.

My proof is in fact a modification of the proof below, which uses *right-monochromatic* vertex sequence as its main tool.

[image]

The same procedure is used in the proof for infinite Ramsey number.

[image]

**My proof:**

Consider an arbitrary 2-colouring of $\mathbb{N} \choose 2$, and let $v_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ be the vertices. If we try to apply the process in the proof of **Claim 2.3.** an infinite number of times, as in the proof of **Theorem 2.6**, but only restrict ourselves to some of the first steps of the procedure, we're bound to arrive at the value $t$ before getting our infinite monochromatic clique.

The details of the procedure is as follows. Let $\{w_1, w_2,..., w_{2t-2}\} \subset \{v_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be the right-monochromatic vertex sequence that we will eventually obtain. Set $w_1 = v_1, \text{and } S_0 = \{v_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Consider the edges from $v_1$ to other $v_i$'s. If either red or blue occurs a finite number of times, then the other colour must occur an infinite number of times, and we set $S_1$ to be the set of vertices of the latter type. Otherwise, both red and blue must occur an infinite number of times, and we choose $S_1$ to be the set of vertices corresponding to either colour.

Given a set $S_i$, then, we set $w_{i+1}$ to be the vertex $v_k \in S_i$ with the lowest index $k$. We consider the edges from $v_k$ to the vertices $v_m \in S_i, \text{with } m > k$, and carry out the same analysis as above, setting $S_{i+1} \subset S_i \setminus \{v_k\}$ to be the set of vertices corresponding to the infinitely-occurring colour.

We note that the sequence $\{w_1,..., w_{2t-2}\}$ constructed this way is indeed right-monochromatic. Once this sequence is obtained, applying the pigeonhole principle on the first $2t - 3$ vertices gives a monochromatic complete graph on $\left\lceil \frac{2t-3}{2} \right\rceil = t-1$, which, together with the last vertex $w_{2t-2}$, forms a monochromatic $K_t$.

The integer $n$ that we're interested in is the index of the vertex $v_n$ such that $w_{2t-2} = v_n$.

Comment: Huh? But the question you stated at the beginning was not "prove the finite Ramsey theorem", it was "deduce the finite Ramsey theorem **from the infinite case**."

Comment: The proof of the infinite case is by construction. In my solution I try to argue that, given an integer $t$, a certain number of first steps of such construction would lead us to an integer $n$ satisfying the finite case. I guess I didn't use the Ramsey's theorem for infinite case per se, but rather its proof. Would it still be valid?

Comment: It may be *valid* (I haven't checked it) but I don't think it's in the spirit of the question. I'd try an argument by contraposition: assuming the finite Ramsey theorem is false, show that the infinite version would also be false.

Comment: If the finite Ramsey theorem is false for $t$, then for each $n$ there is a colouring $$f_n:\binom{\{1,2,\dots,n\}}2\to\{\text{red, blue}\}$$ with no monochromatic $K_t$. The colourings $f_n$ can be chosen (argument needed here) so that $$f_1\subset f_2\subset\cdots\subset f_n\subset\cdots$$ Then $\bigcup_nf_n$ is a colouring which contradicts the infinite Ramsey theorem.

Comment: Note that this kind of argument provides no estimate for the Ramsey number.